# axios post for multiple data with flask and vuejs

Tags: flask, vue.js, axios

All I want to do is get `context_answers` and `treatment_answers` from my web user inputs and bring it on the Flask. (I am very new to this, sorry that I am a vague about what I am doing)

```
`context_answers = {"a":[1], "b":[2], "c":[3], "d":[4]}
treatment_answers = {"y":[10]}`
```

I was able to get context_answers doing following:

```
`methods: {
      handleSubmit() {    
        axios.post("/submit_survey", this.context_answers)
      }
    }`
```

and on the Flask

```
`@app.route("/submit_survey", methods=["POST"])
def submit_survey():
    context = request.get_json(force=True)
    context_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(context)`
```

But how do you get `this.treatments_answers` in the same axios post method? and in the `submit_survey`?

I want to create a data frame that has following:

`a b c d y
1 2 3 4 10`

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Perhaps show an example of each piece of data (ie `context_answers` and `treatments_answers`) and what you'd like the received data to look like in your Flask app

Answer (score 1):

If do you want past many params you can do this:

```
methods: {
  handleSubmit() {    
    axios.post("/submit_survey", {context_answers: this.context_answers, 
                                                         treatments_answers: this.treatments_answers})
  .then( 
     (response) => { console.log(response) },
     (error) => { console.log(error) }
   )
  }
}
```

or try this:

```
 methods: {
      handleSubmit() {    
        axios.post("/submit_survey", {context_answers: this.context_answers, 
                                                             treatments_answers: this.treatments_answers})
      .then(response => { 
         console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
         console.log(error)
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you David. Then how do I request later? I know it is super basic.

Comment: I mean when I had just one context_answer, I used `context = request.get_json(force=True)` to extract it and convert it into pandas data frame. So now how do I save the treatment now?

Comment: in theory you should capture the axion in a variable just like this: `const response = await axios.post( ...` then make a **console.log** of **response** and tell me what you see

Comment: `Promise {<pending>}
__proto__
:
Promise
catch
:
ƒ catch()
arguments
:
(...)`

Comment: I edited my answer, look how the method handleSubmit was, make a console.log of response again and tell me what you see

Comment: It is showing me `spread.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500`

Comment: I edited my answer again, try to see the console of your browser and look the request for see if is sending the params

Comment: it is again the same error. `Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)`

Comment: yeah but is passing the params in the request? you look it in the request? you know in the console of your browser you can see it, in the net tab, maybe that error come from submit_survey and not the request

Comment: Yeah, this is what I see in the console. I would expect to see both context and treatment answers on the console, right?

Comment: in the better case yes, but you have an error 500 so the firts step is watch if in the request the parameters **context_answers** and **treatments_answers** are passing with his values, i mean the error 500 is your response but what's is the request? do you have any form to give me that? including parameters

Comment: I have edited the original question and I put what is in the request there.

Comment: i can't see the request of your browser

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the problem and I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: `@app.route("/submit_survey", methods=["POST"])
def submit_survey():
    context = request.get_json(force=True)
    context_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(context)`

Comment: what's the best way to request to return those *context_answers* and *treatment_answers*?

Comment: another question, that code is running in client or server side?

Comment: Hey, I got it just by adding these two dictionaries in together in the Javascript and request it as one big object. Thanks a lot for your help!